# PDO insert into MSSQL datetime swaps day and month

Tags: sql-server, pdo

When I try to insert a record with date/time into MSSQL 2008 **datetime** field like this

```
$pQuery = "INSERT INTO myTable (myDate) VALUES (:my_date)";
$ps = $pdo->prepare($pQuery);
$ps->bindValue("my_date", date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('01.07.2013')), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ps->execute();
```

with a string '01.07.2013' (DD.MM.YYYY) representing July 1st 2013, I end up with a value of '2013-01-07 00:00:00' in the table which represents January 7th 2013.

If the day is bigger than 12, insert fails with PDOException "SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value".

When I do exactly the same to the **datetime2** field, it is inserted correctly. Anyone has an idea how to circumvent this? Changing the datatype from datetime to datetime2 is not an option. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out elsewhere that using ISO format in date() function inserts the dates correctly regardless of the underlying database field type (datetime, datetime2, smalldatetime). So to avoid the problem in the question use

```
date("Ymd H:i:s")
```

when inserting dates to MS SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
$date = "01.07.2013";
$array = explode(".", $date);
$array = array_reverse($array);
$str = implode($array,"/");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($str));
```

This will output

```
2013-07-01 00:00:00
```

#### [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/TUQKdM)

Comment: `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('01.07.2013'));`
returns correct format (just like yours), problem is with the PDO insert to the database.

Comment: @Bob this will output january, mine is July

Comment: and besides the same code inserts correct date if the field is datetime2, so I guess there's something wrong with PDO insert.